# Wrong module specified can't find ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory

Tags: servicestack

I am getting a "Wrong Module Specified" red squiggly in my web.config for the following lines:

```
<add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack, Version=3.9.38.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
<add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack, Version=3.9.38.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" verb="*"/>
```

FYI, I made sure to not select the Client Profile of version 3.5 of .NET framework as suggested by similar posts.

When I select Resharper's offer to "Fix the module qualification" I still get the error indication in my web.config.

I am following the sample application as provided in the ServiceStack website.  I installed the latest stable release of ServiceStack, here's my package.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="3.9.39" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

When I run the application, I am greeted with this friendly message:

Configuration Error

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.38.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory` type is inside the main **ServiceStack.dll**. If it can't find it than it's not referenced properly which is likely due to either trying to add it to the wrong Profile (e.g. Client Profile) or it's not properly referenced in the Host project where your Web.config is.

Comment: Interesting, Resharper found it and offered to correct it but failed. I can't figure it out. Interestingly, the squiggly line only appears under the ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory. The module appears in my references.  If it helps I am using IIS 7. 

Also, when I remove the ServiceStack reference from the project, the error changes to "cannot resolve symbol"  I can only conclude that it is in fact finding the reference.

Answer (score 3):

This comes up in searches for "could not find ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory."  In my case, the example used in Pluralsight and other places is to add the default handler of `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory`, which is for ServiceStack 3.9.  Upgrading to ServiceStack 4.5.0, the factory is `ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory`.   e.g.:

```
<add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
```

Comment: ran into same issue when following pluralsight course.